# Android Prevent Box From Resizing

Tags: android, android-layout, android-activity, resize

I am trying to make a four function calculator app. The two blank lines are the numbers involved in the calculations. The issue I have is with the 'result' box. Since I used relativelayout, the placement of everything is relative to the 'result' box. If I first calculate, say, 2+2 and 'result' is 4, it's ok. But if I do 5+5 and 'result' is now 10, a two digit number, everything shifts a little because 'result' has changed. Is there a way to let 'result' change size but keep everything else in place?

[image: Picture of current app UI]

Comment: Show us your current xml please!

Comment: Edit it into the original question :)

Comment: http://i.imgur.com/KpBxwVo.png
http://i.imgur.com/1EwafaS.png

Comment: You need to post the whole XML image/file. What you posted above is partial.

Comment: that's it for the xml file, unless you want the mainactivity.java code too?

Answer (score 1):

So you may not use Relative Layout.
But can we use TableLayout?

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<TableLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent">
<TableRow
    android:layout_weight="2"
    android:layout_margin="20dp"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:layout_width="match_parent">
    <EditText
        android:inputType="number"
        android:layout_gravity="bottom"
        android:id="@+id/num_1"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>
    <Space  android:layout_weight="1"
        android:layout_width="0dp"/>
    <EditText
        android:inputType="number"
        android:layout_gravity="bottom"
        android:id="@+id/num_2"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>
</TableRow>
<TableRow
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:layout_margin="20dp"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:layout_width="match_parent">

    <TextView

        android:singleLine="true"
        android:text="Result"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:textSize="24sp"
        android:id="@+id/result"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_column="18" />
</TableRow>
<TableRow
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:layout_margin="20dp"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:layout_width="match_parent">
    <Button
        android:text="ADD"
        android:id="@+id/add"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="3"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>
    <Space
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="2"
        />
    <Button
        android:text="SUBTRACT"
        android:id="@+id/sub"
        android:layout_weight="3"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>
  </TableRow>
  <TableRow
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:layout_margin="20dp"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:layout_width="match_parent">
    <Button
        android:text="MULTIPLY"
        android:id="@+id/multi"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="3"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>
    <Space
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="2"
        />
    <Button
        android:text="DIVIDE"
        android:id="@+id/divide"
        android:layout_weight="3"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>
</TableRow>

</TableLayout>
```

Comment: One thing i read from other stack overflow questions was that RelativeLayout is recommended due to the multitude of android devices on the market, and it will change according to the device. Does TableLayout also accommodate for different devices?

Comment: I'm sorry that I'm a rookie here so I can not post pictures.But I've try this layout on different size of screens on Android Studio(including Nexus one,Nexus s,Nexus 4,5,6),t will change according to the device.