# Android Text Changing Resizes Different Text Box

Tags: android, android-layout, layout, resize

So I'm trying to make a simple four function calculator app. The two blank lines represent the two numbers that the order of operations will be used on. I have an issue with the "Result" resizing when I test the app. If result is one digit, then the two lines will change according to the size of the one digit box because I use relative layout. If I change a number to make the result two digits, it will expand the result box and change the size of the two lines, making them shorter. How can I make it so that the two lines will stay the same size regardless of what happens to Result? (sorry if the images are hard to read)

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: I've flagged this post, because OP asked **exactly the same question** twice - 1 hour earlier http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30689319/android-prevent-box-from-resizing. (I don't know why, but my report has been rejected.)

Answer (score 0):

Insert both the Edit Texts in a LinearLayout and give them weights. I guess it will solve your problem.

```
LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    <EditText
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="0.5"/>
    <EditText
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="0.5" />

</LinearLayout>
```

Its just a code snippet, you have to add the weights like this. Just try this thing. Hope it might solve your problem.

Answer (score 0):

The best solution will be to provide weight to the layout. If you want a gap between the views, add a View in between the edittexts with a weight.

```
LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    <EditText
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"/>

    <View
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="0.5"/>

    <EditText
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1" />

</LinearLayout
```

>